# react-native link fails on all modules

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-cli

I posted this to react-native issues:

Environment

```
Environment:
OS: macOS Sierra 10.12.6
Node: 7.10.0
Yarn: 1.3.2
npm: 5.6.0
Watchman: 4.7.0
Xcode: Xcode 8.0 Build version 8A218a
Android Studio: 1.5 AI-141.2456560

Packages: (wanted => installed)
react: 16.0.0-alpha.12 => 16.0.0-alpha.12
react-native: 0.48.0 => 0.48.0
```

Steps to Reproduce

```
react-native link react-native-fbsdk
or simply
react-native link
```

Expected Behavior

I thought it would link react-native-fbsdk

Actual Behavior

```
rnpm-install ERR! ERRPACKAGEJSON No package found. Are you sure this is a React Native project?

Cannot read property '_text' of undefined
```

Reproducible Demo

This is a tooling issue, can only reproduce at command line, doesn't matter what the app is.

Comment: Have you followed the steps mentioned in this link https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk ??

Answer (score 1):

Install fbsdk using `react-native install react-native-fbsdk` and then try linking to your project `react-native link react-native-fbsdk` for further info refer [documentation](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk#2-install-javascript-packages)